# why does text stop following the player when I restart the scene in phaser 3

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

I have 2 scenes, a gameplay scene and a result screen scene, when I click on the retry button within the result screen scene everything restarts as intended but the text is no longer following the player. It is instead positioned in relation to where the player touched the goal flag that leads to the result screen.

below is all of the code involved with the text within the game and the respective functions.

```
class gameScene extends Phaser.Scene{

preload(){
gameScene.seconds = 0
this.interval = setInterval(counter, 1000);
}

create(){
gameScene.Text = this.add.text(this.player.x+50, this.player.y-50, { fontSize: '16px', fill: '#fff' });

gameScene.Text.setText(0);
}

update(){
gameScene.Text.x=this.player.x+50
gameScene.Text.y=this.player.y-50
}
}

function counter(){
    gameScene.seconds = gameScene.seconds+1
    gameScene.Text.setText(gameScene.seconds)
}
```

[image: before clicking retry]
[image: after clicking retry]

any and all help will be appreciated.
thanks a lot :)

edit: below is the entire current code of the game.

```js
class gameScene extends Phaser.Scene {


     preload(){
        gameScene.seconds = 0
        this.k=0
        this.velocity = 0
        this.endReached = false
        this.facingLeft=false
        this.facingRight=false
        this.interval = setInterval(counter, 1000);
        //load stage and tileset
        this.load.image('tiles', 'assets/skyTileset.png');
        this.load.image('goalFlag','assets/goalFlag.png')
        this.load.tilemapTiledJSON('sky', 'assets/bouncy_shrooms.json');
        //loading assets into game
        this.load.spritesheet('player', 'assets/player.png',
        { frameWidth: 16, frameHeight: 16 }
            );

    };
     create(){
        //create assets within the game
        this.skyMap = this.make.tilemap({key: 'sky'});
        this.tileset = this.skyMap.addTilesetImage('skyShrooms','tiles');
        this.background = this.skyMap.createLayer('sky', this.tileset,);           
        this.platforms = this.skyMap.createLayer('platforms', this.tileset,);
        this.stems = this.skyMap.createLayer('stems', this.tileset,);
        this.platforms.setCollisionByExclusion([-1]);
    
        this.goal = this.physics.add.sprite(1200, 87, 'goalFlag')
        this.goal.setScale(0.1)
        this.goal.body.setAllowGravity(false);
        this.goal.setImmovable(true)

        this.physics.world.setBounds(0,0,1280,960)
        //loading the player sprite as a physics based sprite.
        //this.player = this.physics.add.sprite(50,850,"player");
        this.player = this.physics.add.sprite(1000,50,"player");
        this.player.setScale(1.75)
        this.player.setCollideWorldBounds(true)
        this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.platforms);
        

        
        Text = this.add.text(this.player.x+50, this.player.y-50, { fontSize: '16px', fill: '#fff' });

        Text.setText(0);
   
        //player animations
    
        this.anims.create({
            key: "left-idle",
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('player', { start: 1, end: 1 }),
            frameRate: 0,
            repeat: -1

        })
        this.anims.create({
            key: "right-idle",
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('player', {start: 0, end: 0}),
            frameRate: 0,
            repeat: -1
        })
        this.anims.create({
            key:"left-walk",
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('player', {start: 6, end: 9}),
            frameRate: 8,
            repeat: -1
        })
        this.anims.create({
            key:"right-walk",
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('player', {start: 2, end: 5}),
            frameRate: 8,
            repeat: -1
        })
        this.anims.create({
            key:"right-jump",
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('player', {start: 10, end: 10}),
            frameRate: 0,
            repeat: -1
        })
        this.anims.create({
            key:"right-fall",
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('player', {start: 11, end: 11}),
            frameRate: 0,
            repeat: -1
        })
        this.anims.create({
            key:"left-jump",
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('player', {start: 12, end: 12}),
            frameRate: 0,
            repeat: -1
        })
        this.anims.create({
            key:"left-fall",
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('player', {start: 13, end: 13}),
            frameRate: 0,
            repeat: -1
        })
        

        //camera
        this.cameras.main.startFollow(this.player);
        this.cameras.main.setBounds(0,0,1280,960);
    };
     update(){
        
        //text always within player view
        

        this.cameras.main.zoom = 2
        Text.x=this.player.x+50
        Text.y=this.player.y-50
        //get variable for player velocity
        this.velocity=this.player.body.velocity.x;
        //creating arrow key input
        this.cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
        //creating key input
        this.keyW = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.W);
        this.keyA = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.A);
        this.keyS = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.S);
        this.keyD = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.D);
        //player movement
        if (this.endReached == false){
        if (this.cursors.left.isDown || this.keyA.isDown){
            this.player.setVelocityX(-90)
            console.log("left")
            this.player.anims.play('left-walk', true)
        }
        else if (this.cursors.right.isDown || this.keyD.isDown){
            this.player.setVelocityX(90)
            console.log("right")
            this.player.anims.play('right-walk', true)
        }
        else{
            this.player.setVelocityX(0)
                if (this.facingLeft == true){
                    this.player.anims.play('right-idle',true);
                    }
                    else if (this.facingRight == true){
                    this.player.anims.play('left-idle',true);
                    };
        }
        if ((this.cursors.up.isDown || this.keyW.isDown) && this.player.body.onFloor()){
            this.player.setVelocityY(-180)
            console.log("up")
            
        }}
        if (this.velocity < 0){
            this.facingRight = true;
            this.facingLeft = false;
        }
        else if(this.velocity > 0){
            this.facingLeft = true;
            this.facingRight = false;
        };
    
        this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.goal, endCollision,null,this);

        
    };
}

class timeTrialEnd extends Phaser.Scene{
    preload(){
        this.load.image('finished','assets/finishedBackground.png' )
        this.load.image('retryButton','assets/retryButton.png')
    }
    
    create(){
        this.add.image(640,480,'finished')
        this.add.text(100, 500, { fontSize: '16px', fill: '#000' })
        .setText('You completed the stage in '+gameScene.seconds+' seconds!').setScale(3);
        console.log("loaded")
        
        const retryButton = this.add.image(100,800,'retryButton').setInteractive()


        retryButton.on('pointerdown', () => {game.scene.add('gameScene', gameScene, true, { x: 1280, y: 960 });
        game.scene.remove('timeTrialEnd');
        console.log('loaded')

        });
    }
}
    // timer function

function counter(){
    gameScene.seconds = gameScene.seconds+1
    this.Text.setText(gameScene.seconds)
}
function endCollision(){
while (this.k == 0){
clearInterval(this.interval)
this.endReached = true
this.player.anims.stop()
game.scene.add('timeTrialEnd', timeTrialEnd, true, { x: 1280, y: 960 });
game.scene.remove('gameScene');
this.k+=1
}}



var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    pixelArt: true,
    width: 1280,
    height: 960,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            gravity: { y: 200 },
            debug: true
        }
    },

        scene: gameScene
    };


var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

ANSWERED

thanks to a kind coder I have gotten a solution to the problem.

```js
        this.seconds = 0;
        this.interval = setInterval(
        () => {  //  <- this is a inline arrow function see mdn link for details
            this.seconds = this.seconds + 1
            this.timerText.setText(this.seconds)
        },1000);
```

the main part of the solution is to add this code snippet into the create function instead of establishing an interval that leads to an external function. This, as stated in their answer will put the text variable within the interval into context of the scene. After I deleted the establishing of an interval in preload() and the external function. change every involved variable or object to have this. before it and it now works (for me anyway). thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a some ***issues***, that I can identify at first glance ***(Check the final "Update" for the full solution)*** :

1. Why is the `Text` bound to the class (`gameScene`) and not the instance *(`this`)*. *This is probably the main cause of the error.*
   **btw.:** I would name classes in javascript *pascal case*, so `class GameScene ...` just to avoid confusion.
2. Where is the `this.player` set? I can't see it in the `create` function, where one would usually find it. The `Text` shouldn't be displayed since `this.player` is likely `undefined`. *Check the browser console for errors*
3. **optional:** `setInterval` I personally would always use the phaser builtin function `this.time.addEvent`, over core javascript other libraries, when possible. Checkout [this official example](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/time/repeat-count) for a nice alternative

**So to solve the problem**, I would recommend:

1. attach the `Text` to the class instance , *but rename it to something like `this.playerInfoText` to avoid naimg collisions*
2. ensure the the player *(`this.player`)* is create in the `create` function of the scene, so that the `x` and `y` properties can be read and set correct
3. **finally:** check the browser console for other related errors

**Update, *after question was updated*:**

You should change the `Text` variable:

From this:

```
create(){
    ...
    Text = this.add.text(this.player.x+50, this.player.y-50, { fontSize: '16px', fill: '#fff' });
    Text.setText(0);
    ...
}
```

To this *(and any other place you are using the `Text`)*:

```
create(){
    ...
    this.playerInfoText = this.add.text(this.player.x+50, this.player.y-50, { fontSize: '16px', fill: '#fff' });
    this.playerInfoText.setText(0);
    ...
}
```

**Update 2:**

The reason why the counter throws an error is that the context ist not more correct. *([details mdn article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this))*

**Solution, to comment**

delete this lines from the `preload`function:

```
gameScene.seconds = 0
this.interval = setInterval(counter, 1000);
```

and after the creation of the `this.player`and `this.playerInfoText`( as mentioned above) just add the counter creation and inline the function:

```
this.seconds = 0;
this.interval = setInterval(
    () => {  //  <- this is a inline arrow function see mdn link for details
     this.seconds = this.seconds + 1
     this.playerInfoText.setText(this.seconds)
 });
```

or using with the builtin `addEvent` function instead of `setInterval` (also in the `create` function):

```
this.seconds = 0;
this.interval = scene.time.addEvent({
    delay: 1000,
    callback: counter,
    callbackScope: this,
    loop: true
});
...
// some tweaks have to be done on the counter function, for this to work
function counter(){
    this.seconds = this.seconds+1
    this.playerInfoText.setText(this.seconds)
}
```

Comment: 'this.player = this.physics.add.sprite(1000,50,"player");
        this.player.setScale(1.75)
        this.player.setCollideWorldBounds(true)
        this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.platforms);
        

        
        Text = this.add.text(this.player.x+50, this.player.y-50, { fontSize: '16px', fill: '#fff' });

        Text.setText(0);'  this is the code of the player and text in the create function

Comment: when using this. before the text variable, when the .setText in the counter function tries to update the text, i get a type error saying that the properties are undefined.

Comment: @Genesiscookie I updated my answer to explain, how to solve the problem with the `counter` function. The why the problem happens can be found in the mdn link in the answer

Comment: im sorry, im really dumb, ive just re read the answer and ive edited my code to have the interval function thing within gameScene and it now works as intended thanks a lot

Comment: @Genesiscookie main thing is that it works, enjoy your phaser development journey :) btw.: if it works consider accepting my answer with the greeen checkmark near the voting arrows.